# Perl variable that takes different values

Tags: perl

I need to upload files with different names in the same format like this:
`file_name_yyyy-mm-dd_code.txt`

How can I write it in Perl?

Right now I can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Config::Simple;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
use Net::Google::Drive::Simple;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use Storable;

# my $date = strftime '%m-%d-%Y', localtime;
# for testing purpose, use specific date
my $date = '2018-07-16'; 
my $code;
# $code will change


my $gd = Net::Google::Drive::Simple->new();
my ($p1, $folder) = $gd->children("Test");
$folder = <folder id>;

$gd->file_upload("testfile_${date}_${code}.txt", $folder);
```

and it uploads files with this format in the same folder as the `perl` file:
`file_name_yyyy-mm-dd.txt`

but it doesn't upload files with this format (which I need to do): `file_name_yyyy-mm-dd_somecode.txt`

For example:
`file_name_2018-07-16_code1.txt` or `file_name_2018-07-16_code2.txt`

I have absolutely no experience with Perl so I don't even know where to look.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't upload files"? Does the file exist locally? Do you get an error message back from Net::Google::Drive::Simple?

Comment: You can't create a file name like `file_name_yyyy-mm-dd.txt` with the expression `"testfile_${date}_${code}.txt"`. Even if `$code` is empty, it will create `file_name_yyyy-mm-dd_.txt` with a trailing underscore.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I don't mean to create the files. Those files are already in the same folder with the pl file. I just need to use the pl file to upload all the text files with the name format name-date-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, in

```
"file_name_$date_$code.txt"
```

`$date_` is a valid variable name, but not the one you want. Delineate the identifiers with braces, like this

```
"file_name_${date}_${code}.txt"
```

Or you can use `sprintf`, like this

```
sprintf 'file_name_%s_%s.txt', $date, $code
```

which produces the same result

Comment: Thanks @Borodin. It does take the value of $date and uploads file like this: file_name_yyyy-mm-dd.txt but it doesn't upload files with names like this: file_name_yyyy-mm-dd_somecode.txt

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: uploading files with different dates and different codes.

Comment: @Viet Your comments are too ambiguous. You'll have to show some more code if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't been very clear in describing what you want, but I wonder if you're looking for [`glob()`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/glob).

```
for my $file (glob("file_name_${date}_*.txt")) {
  $gd->file_upload($file, $folder);
}
```

You can adjust the string you pass to `glob()` so it gives you whatever files your really want.